# PHP session expired error on localhost XAMPP server but when i upload the project on remoter it's working without error

Tags: php, session, xampp, localhost

Hi I would appreciate if someone can help me with the issue. I have spent almost three days trying to solve the issue but I couldn't.

**My `session.php` file:**

```
<?
class Session
{
   var $time;         //Time 
   var $url;          //The page url 

   /* Class constructor */
   function Session(){
     // $this->time = time();
      $this->startSession();
      //$_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (1 * 60) ; // ending a session in 30     minutes from the starting time

   }

   function startSession(){
      //global $database;  //The database connection
      session_start();   //Tell PHP to start the session
      /* Set referrer page */
      if(isset($_SESSION['url'])){
         $this->referrer = $_SESSION['url'];
      }else{
         $this->referrer = "/";
      }
      /* Set current url */
      $this->url = $_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

   }
};
//-----------------------------------------
// Start new wession
//-----------------------------------------
$session = new Session;
?>
```

**Localhost output see below:**

```
time = time(); $this->startSession(); //$_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (1 * 60) ; // ending a session in 30 minutes from the starting time } function startSession(){ //global $database; //The database connection session_start(); //Tell PHP to start the session /* Set referrer page */ if(isset($_SESSION['url']) && $_SESSION['url'] != '/index.php'){ $this->referrer = $_SESSION['url']; }else{ $this->referrer = "/"; } /* Set current url */ $this->url = $_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; } }; //----------------------------------------- // Start new wession //----------------------------------------- $session = new Session; ?> 1) ? 's':''; return count($items); }*/ $uniqCustomerId = $_SESSION['uCustomerId']; //dmWListTotalLeft(); $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `wishlist` where `uniqCustomerId` = $uniqCustomerId"); //$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query); if(mysql_num_rows($query) !=0) { return mysql_num_rows($query); }else{ return 0; } } //----------------------------------------- // Total items //----------------------------------------- function dmWListTotal() { if(!isset ( $_SESSION['dm_cartmj01'])){ $dm_cart = 0; }else{ $dm_cart = $_SESSION['dm_cartmj01']; } if (!$dm_cart) { //echo "Your Wishlist is empty"; $dm_cart = 0; return ''; } else { //echo "Your Wishlist"; // Parse the cart session variable $items = explode(',',$dm_cart); $s = (count($items) > 1) ? 's':''; return '
You have '.count($items).' item'.$s.' in your wishlist
'; } } // Back to catalogue //----------------------------------------- // Show List NEW //----------------------------------------- function dmWListShowNew() { // init $uniqCustomerId = $_SESSION['uCustomerId']; //dmWListTotalLeft(); $sn = 1; $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `wishlist` where `uniqCustomerId` = $uniqCustomerId"); $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result); // START if items exists in wishlist if($num_rows == 0){ $output[] = "
Your wishlist is empty
"; }else{ $output[] = '
'; while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { $id = $row['itemId']; $output[] = '
'; // ul start1 $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `products` where prod_id ='".$id."LIMIT 1'"); while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) { $output[] = '
'.$sn.'
'; $output[] = '
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?

?>
```

instead of that use below tag

```
<?php

?>
```

Updated:
i have updated the class with Hello() method it will return larvel hello

```
<?php

class Session
{
   var $time;         //Time 
   var $url;          //The page url 

   /* Class constructor */
   function Session(){
     // $this->time = time();
      $this->startSession();
      //$_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (1 * 60) ; // ending a session in 30     minutes from the starting time

   }
function Hello(){

echo "laravel hello";

}
   function startSession(){
      //global $database;  //The database connection
      session_start();   //Tell PHP to start the session
      /* Set referrer page */
      if(isset($_SESSION['url'])){
         $this->referrer = $_SESSION['url'];
      }else{
         $this->referrer = "/";
      }
      /* Set current url */
      $this->url = $_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

   }
};
//-----------------------------------------
// Start new wession
//-----------------------------------------
$session = new Session;
$session->Hello();
?>
```

Comment: I highly doubt that's the problem unless the OP is using a very outdated version of Apache or another web server.

Comment: Thank you so mcuh for quick reply Mr.Prakash Lobo. After I change the code in session php file the index page is completely blank.

Comment: yes.you are class methods not returning any think.l have updated answer with new method called Hello()